# How to receive a file via HTTP PUT with PHP

Tags: php, file, http, put

This is something that has been bugging me for a while.. I'm building of a RESTful API that has to receive files on some occasions.

When using `HTTP POST`, we can read `data from $_POST` and `files from $_FILES`.

When using `HTTP GET`, we can read `data from $_GET` and `files from $_FILES`.

However, when using `HTTP PUT`, AFAIK the only way to read data is to use the `php://input stream`.

All good and well, untill I want to send a file over HTTP PUT. Now the php://input stream doesn't work as expected anymore, since it has a file in there as well.

Here's how I currently read data on a PUT request:

(which works great as long as there are no files posted)

```
$handle  = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$rawData = '';
while ($chunk = fread($handle, 1024)) {
    $rawData .= $chunk;
}

parse_str($rawData, $data);
```

When I then output rawData, it shows

```
-----ZENDHTTPCLIENT-44cf242ea3173cfa0b97f80c68608c4c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_01"; filename="lorem-ipsum.png"
Content-Type: image/png; charset=binary

�PNG
���...etc etc...
���,
-----ZENDHTTPCLIENT-8e4c65a6678d3ef287a07eb1da6a5380
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testkey"

testvalue
-----ZENDHTTPCLIENT-8e4c65a6678d3ef287a07eb1da6a5380
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="otherkey"

othervalue
```

Does anyone know how to properly receive files over HTTP PUT, or how to parse files out of the php://input stream?

**===== UPDATE #1 =====**

I have tried only the above method, don't really have a clue as to what I can do else.

I have gotten no errors using this method, besides that I don't get the desired result of the posted data and files.

**===== UPDATE #2 =====**

I'm sending this test request using Zend_Http_Client, as follows:
(haven't had any problems with Zend_Http_Client so far)

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setConfig(array(
    'strict'       => false,
    'maxredirects' => 0,
    'timeout'      => 30)
);
$client->setUri( 'http://...' );
$client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::PUT);
$client->setFileUpload( dirname(__FILE__) . '/files/lorem-ipsum.png', 'image_01');
$client->setParameterPost(array('testkey' => 'testvalue', 'otherkey' => 'othervalue');
$client->setHeaders(array(
    'api_key'    => '...',
    'identity'   => '...',
    'credential' => '...'
));
```

**===== SOLUTION =====**

Turns out I made some wrong assumptions, mainly that HTTP PUT would be similar to HTTP POST. As you can read below, DaveRandom explained to me that HTTP PUT is not meant for transferring multiple files on the same request.

I have now moved the transferring of formdata from the body to url querystring. The body now holds the contents of a single file.

For more information, read DaveRandom's answer. It's epic.

Comment: eh? What errors do you get then you try doing that?

Comment: How you are sending the request? php://input does not work only in multipart requests...

Comment: multipart/formdata should result in a populated $_FILES.

Comment: @Jack Not with the PUT method.

Comment: @DaveRandom that's unfortunate :) that leaves just the option of manual mime decoding.

Comment: @Jack that sounds like something that would work. I have no experience with that whatsoever. Do u know a way/technique that would help me to do this?

Comment: @Maurice Parsing multipart messages is not hard but it is not the answer here. The answer is to make your put request valid in the first place so it isn't necessary

Comment: @Jack It's not "unfortunate", it's *correct, RFC-compliant behaviour...* ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom Just to get my basics right, what is the *correct* way to send and receive a PUT request? Where is form-data supposed to go, and where are files contents supposed to go?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The data you show does not depict a valid PUT request body (well, it *could*, but I highly doubt it). What it shows is a `multipart/form-data` request body - the MIME type used when uploading files via HTTP POST through an HTML form.

PUT requests should exactly compliment the response to a GET request - they send you the file contents in the message body, and nothing else.

Essentially what I'm saying is that it is not your code to receive the file that is wrong, it is the code that is making the request - the client code is incorrect, not the code you show here (although the `parse_str()` call is a pointless exercise).

If you explain what the client is (a browser, script on other server, etc) then I can help you take this further. As it is, the appropriate request method for the request body that you depict is POST, not PUT.

---

Let's take a step back from the problem, and look at the HTTP protocol in general - specifically the client request side - hopefully this will help you understand how all of this is supposed to work. First, a little history (if you're not interested in this, feel free to skip this section).

***History***

HTTP was originally designed as a mechanism for retrieving HTML documents from remote servers. At first it effectively supported only the GET method, whereby the client would request a document by name and the server would return it to the client. The first public specification for HTTP, labelled as HTTP 0.9, appeared in 1991 - and if you're interested, you can read it [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html).

The HTTP 1.0 specification (formalised in 1996 with [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945)) expanded the capabilities of the protocol considerably, adding the HEAD and POST methods. It was not backwards compatible with HTTP 0.9, due to a change in the format of the response - a response code was added, as well as the ability to include metadata for the returned document in the form of MIME format headers - key/value data pairs. HTTP 1.0 also abstracted the protocol from HTML, allowing for the transfer of files and data in other formats.

HTTP 1.1, the form of the protocol that is almost exclusively in use today is built on top of HTTP 1.0 and was designed to be backwards compatible with HTTP 1.0 implementations. It was standardised in 1999 with [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html). If you are a developer working with HTTP, get to know this document - it is your bible. Understanding it fully will give you a considerable advantage over your peers who do not.

***Get to the point already***

HTTP works on a request-response architecture - the client sends a request message to the server, the server returns a response message to the client.

A request message includes a METHOD, a URI and optionally, a number of HEADERS. The request METHOD is what this question relates to, so it is what I will cover in the most depth here - but first it is important to understand exactly what we mean when we talk about the request URI.

The URI is the location on the server of the resource we are requesting. In general, this consists of a *path* component, and optionally a *query string*. There are circumstances where other components may be present as well, but for the purposes of simplicity we shall ignore them for now.

Let's imagine you type `http://server.domain.tld/path/to/document.ext?key=value` into the address bar of your browser. The browser dismantles this string, and determines that it needs to connect to an HTTP server at `server.domain.tld`, and ask for the document at `/path/to/document.ext?key=value`.

The generated HTTP 1.1 request will look (at a minimum) like this:

```
GET /path/to/document.ext?key=value HTTP/1.1
Host: server.domain.tld
```

The first part of the request is the word `GET` - this is the request METHOD. The next part is the path to the file we are requesting - this is the request URI. At the end of this first line is an identifier indicating the protocol version in use. On the following line you can see a header in MIME format, called `Host`. HTTP 1.1 mandates that the `Host:` header be included with every request. This is the only header of which this is true.

The request URI is broken into two parts - everything to the left of the question mark `?` is the *path*, everything to the right of it is the *query string*.

***Request Methods***

RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1) defines [8 request methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6).

`OPTIONS`

The OPTIONS method is rarely used. It is intended as a mechanism for determining what kind of functionality the server supports before attempting to consume a service the server may provide.

Off the top of my head, the only place in fairly common usage that I can think of where this is used is when opening documents in Microsoft office directly over HTTP from Internet Explorer - Office will send an OPTIONS request to the server to determine if it supports the PUT method for the specific URI, and if it does it will open the document in a way that allows the user to save their changes to the document directly back to the remote server. This functionality is tightly integrated within these specific Microsoft applications.

`GET`

This is by far and away the most common method in every day usage. Every time you load a regular document in your web browser it will be a GET request.

The GET method requests that the server return a specific document. The only data that should be transmitted to the server is information that the server requires to determine which document should be returned. This can include information that the server can use to dynamically generate the document, which is sent in the form of headers and/or query string in the request URI. While we're on the subject - Cookies are sent in the request headers.

`HEAD`

This method is identical to the GET method, with one difference - the server will not return the requested document, if will only return the headers that would be included in the response. This is useful for determining, for example, if a particular document exists without having to transfer and process the entire document.

`POST`

This is the second most commonly used method, and arguably the most complex. POST method requests are almost exclusively used to invoke some actions on the server that may change its state.

A POST request, unlike GET and HEAD, can (and usually does) include some data in the body of the request message. This data can be in any format, but most commonly it is a query string (in the same format as it would appear in the request URI) or a multipart message that can communicate key/value pairs along with file attachments.

Many HTML forms use the POST method. In order to upload files from a browser, you would need to use the POST method for your form.

The POST method is semantically incompatible with RESTful APIs because it is not [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). That is to say, a second identical POST request may result in a further change to the state of the server. This contradicts the "stateless" constraint of REST.

`PUT`

This directly complements GET. Where a GET requests indicates that the server should return the document at the location specified by the request URI in the response body, the PUT method indicates that the server should store the data in the request body at the location specified by the request URI.

`DELETE`

This indicates that the server should destroy the document at the location indicated by the request URI. Very few internet facing HTTP server implementations will perform any action when they receive a DELETE request, for fairly obvious reasons.

`TRACE`

This provides an application-layer level mechanism to allow clients to inspect the request it has sent as it looks by the time it reaches the destination server. This is mostly useful for determining the effect that any proxy servers between the client and the destination server may be having on the request message.

`CONNECT`

HTTP 1.1 reserves the name for a CONNECT method, but does not define its usage, or even its purpose. Some proxy server implementations have since used the CONNECT method to facilitate HTTP tunnelling.

Comment: My god. If this is true then I've made a big mistake in believing PUT would be like POST. For testing, the client is just another php script on the server. I have changed sending parameters via GET now, which only leaves the file contents in the body. - with an additional header, exactly like the one depicted in my question. I believe this content-header MUST be present, how would one otherwise send multiple files over the same request? Any clue as to how I can parse the file out of the body content?

Comment: @Maurice What you are looking at is the content body. Because it is currently in a format that is part of the `multipart/*` family of MIME types, this also carries with it "headers" in the body. The headers that you want to send in a PUT request, however, should be sent in the actual head of the request, and the body should contain nothing but the file data. How does your client PHP script send the request? Via cURL?

Comment: sorry if I don't use the right terms. I did mean the mime "headers" in my message. I'm using Zend_Http_Client, with the default _Socket adapter. This adapter uses stream_socket_client.

Comment: I understand what you say about file contents being the only thing in the request body. But how would you send multiple files without any mime "headers"? I can imagine these mime "headers" would always need to be there?

Comment: @Maurice The raw HTTP request should look like this: http://pastebin.com/TQQnduTz - notice how the `Content-Type:` describing the image appears in the head of the request. It is also important that the `Content-Length:` header matches the byte-length of the file being transferred exactly. A PUT request does not use a `Content-Disposition:` header, instead it determines the name of the file being uploaded from the Request-URI (the path in the first line of the request)

Comment: @Maurice PUT requests would carry any form data as a query string in the request URI (the same place it goes in a GET request).

Comment: So, the content body of a PUT request should never be `multipart/*`?

Comment: I have gotten Zend_Http_Client so far as to only send file content in the body, by using the `$client->setRawData()` method. How would I encode multiple files in the body?

Comment: @Maurice The PUT method is not suitable for sending multiple files in a single request. You would need to use the POST method, or multiple requests. For a truly restful API, that would mandate multiple requests.

Comment: @Maurice The content of a PUT request body *could* be a `multipart/*` type, but **only if this is the format of the file you are transmitting**. For example if you were uploading an email message body via HTTP PUT, this would likely have a `multipart/alternative` MIME type.

Comment: Aaah, so that's another big thing I've been missing. I assumed it would be exactly like POST, also in sending files. I will then have to implement it like you explain. Thank you so very much for helping me out. If you care to explain even more; how would you correctly implement multiple requests?

Comment: @Maurice That would depend on your application architecture. Officially (i.e. as laid out by the relevant RFCs) a PUT request is writing a document to a specific location on the server, based purely on the path portion of the request URI. So if I PUT some data to `/index.html`, it is expected that the server will write that data to the `/index.html` file, so that a subsequent GET request would return the same data. However in practice, it is possible to include a query string in the request URI (like a GET request) which the server can then use to determine where the file should be stored.

Comment: It would be best to use just the URI to determine where the document belongs if possible, so that the RFC description of a 1-to-1 relationship between the URIs used in a GET/PUT request holds true. This does not mean that your local file system must be organised in the same way - or even that the documents themselves must exist. It might help you understand how it is *supposed* to work if you take into account the fact that there is also a DELETE method. Can you explain more about the nature of what your API does?

Comment: The nature of what it does is really simple; provide a central place to store data. Users can authenticate and then store some data, send messages, post logs etc. In case of this PUT request, it is updating data for a user's contact (name, address, phone, etc, with a contact picture). Right now I don't need to send multiple files on single PUT request, but I wanted to ask you because you seem to know your stuff.

Comment: @Maurice Well the way that I would implement that is based on the user's ID. So they would `PUT /<user-id>/contact-info.txt` and then your application can extract the user ID from the URI path and use that to determine where to store the file data - in the local file system, in a database, whatever. And I notice that initially you were sending an image, let's suppose that's a profile picture, well for that the user would `PUT /<user-id>/profile.png` - and again you have that ID to determine what to do with the data.

Comment: One thing to bare in mind is that PUT is not particularly user-friendly because browsers don't tend to easily support it (I don't know if HTML5 makes some provision for it? Possibly). What sort of interface are you providing for this? An HTML driven GUI type interface or just an API that requires some programming knowledge?

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate explanation. You have helped my out a LOT today. 
API will be used mainly by mobile apps. It is not planned to be ever used through a browser. Client has specifically requested a RESTful API.

Comment: @Maurice No worries. I have expanded my answer above for reference purposes - I have come across many people in the past who have a similar misunderstanding of the PUT method, hopefully now I can just link them here. Let me know if there is anything you don't understand as I would like to make this a point of reference that will explain in (relatively) simple terms how this is all supposed to work (in theory).

Comment: Mother of god.. That is a nice explanation. How can I upvote you a thousand times more?

Answer (score 6):

I've never tried using PUT (GET POST and FILES were sufficient for my needs) but this example is from the php docs so it might help you (http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php):

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

Comment: This would sound logical, except that this outputs the file headers as well. Plus this would write the PUTDATA to file as well. So like I expected, this method will save a corrupt file.

Comment: @Maurice:  Have you actually tried it yet?  Or are you just making that assumption?

Comment: I just tried it for you. Like it says in the code, it just writes everything from the php://input stream to a file, which in my case then becomes corrupt since it contains other data than just the file. To be clear; in my case the php://input stream contains two things: 1) regular PUT DATA (like form-data) and 2) and uploaded file. I'll update my question above. Thanks for thinking along though!!

Comment: Sorry if I came over impatient. I really do appreciate you thinking along. This example from the docs has just frustrated me in the past, since I think they oversimplified it.

Comment: Turns out you are spot on and I had my communication wrong. I expected to be able send multiple files over the same request.

Comment: Doesn't work. [Fri May 09 16:14:45 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  parse error in /Library/WebServer/Documents/put.php on line 3

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution that I found to be the most useful.

`$put = array();
 parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $put);`

`$put` will be an array, just like you are used to seeing in `$_POST`, except now you can follow true REST HTTP protocol.

Comment: By far the easiest answer here.  Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use POST and include an X- header to indicate the actual method (PUT in this case).  Usually this is how one works around a firewall which does not allow methods other than GET and POST. Simply declare PHP buggy (since it refuses to handle multipart PUT payloads, it IS buggy), and treat it as you would an outdated/draconian firewall.

The opinions as to what PUT means in relation to GET are just that, opinions. The HTTP makes no such requirement. It simply states 'equivalent' .. it is up to the designer to determine what 'equivalent' means. If your design can accept a multi-file upload PUT and produce an 'equivalent' representation for a subsequent GET for the same resource, that's just fine and dandy, both technically and philosophically, with the HTTP specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow what it says in the [DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php#example-345):

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

This **should** read the whole file that is on the PUT stream and save it locally, then you could do what you want with it.