# $_FILES is not working in PUT and DELETE

Tags: php

I am writing API for my mobile app. I have a problem in PUT and DELETE. In post method , I can use `$_FILES` for uploading file. However, it return NULL value in PUT and DELETE method.

I just use simple code for testing

```
<?php

echo "FILE: ";
var_dump($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
?>
```

I am using [POSTMAN chrome extension](https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension/wiki) for testing the PUT and DELETE method.

Comment: Are You sure there is such an array when using PUT or DELETE?

Comment: Are You using Your form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to receive a file via HTTP PUT with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005790/how-to-receive-a-file-via-http-put-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are You using Your form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?

There is almost the same problem thread - check it: [How to receive a file via HTTP PUT with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005790/how-to-receive-a-file-via-http-put-with-php)

Comment: You can't use a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` because you can't generate a PUT or DELETE request with a form