# Codeigniter REST PUT method not working for form-data

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, rest

As the title says is there any work around , i am just using the example provided in Phil sturgeon REST API for codeigniter.

Using Google chrome post man api client, when i send a data of foo=hello. Form-data will have a value of bool false which means null.

But when using x-www-form-urlencoded, i can see the value.

As i am trying to upload a image file using the PUT method i must be able to send it via form-data.

Any help to shed light on this question would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to access via browser to see if you're authenticating appropriately.

Comment: Thanks but that did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the a PUT request is not suppose to work with multipart/form-data , according to the HTTP specs

This question is also a duplicate of [How to receive a file via HTTP PUT with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005790/how-to-receive-a-file-via-http-put-with-php)