# PHP file upload PUT request alters file, while POST does not

Tags: php, apache

I have the following code, just designed to take a file from either a PUT request or a POST request and copy it to the server.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='PUT') {

    $putdata = fopen("php://input","r");
    $fp = fopen("myputfile.ext","w");

    while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
            fwrite($fp, $data);

    fclose($fp);
    fclose($putdata);

} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['package']['tmp_name'], "mypostfile.ext");
}
```

So for a POST request, the file (which is a zip file in this case) is unchanged. With a PUT request, the file is altered.

```
[root@vm-centos6-010 put]# diff myputfile.ext ../post/mypostfile.ext 
Binary files myputfile.ext and ../post/mypostfile.ext differ
```

It is a zip file, and according to `unzip`, there are an extra 165 bytes added at the beginning. It still unzips successfully, but the warning message does not occur with the POST'ed file. The only other clue I really have is that the file sizes differ by 211 bytes.

I've combed through the php documentation and a dozen or so posts, but I can't figure out why these two methods would differ.

Any insight?

Thanks.

Comment: Open the modified ZIP file in a text editor. My guess is that there's a message being added to the buffer by some process.

Comment: You're correct! `cat` dumps a bunch of unreadable stuff, but when I look in vim I can see certain extra text.

`------WebKitFormBoundaryhPjNpS0gBhbCC8aR^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="package"; filename="warmup.0.6.5.1.nupkg"^M
Content-Type: application/octet-stream^M
^M`

Now I gotta figure out how to ignore this stuff...

Comment: That's very interesting. It would seem that the raw input stream is being stripped of its headers and content boundary(s) when you grab it via POST but that it's all still there via PUT. Are you positive you're handling POST and PUT identically on the client side?

Comment: I'm using the Advanced REST client app for google chrome. It's always served me well up until now, so I was more inclined to believe that the problem was in my understanding of how PHP handles data, but now it seems like the way it encodes the request is perhaps the culprit.

Comment: Upon further investigation, other clients that produce PUT requests also add this header data, so I am back to my original problem of stripping this header data before processing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^M` are windows line ending characters `CR LF` (`0x0D 0x0A` or `\r\n`).

When opening the stream `$putdata = fopen("php://input","r");`

The headers are sent first and then the file (header and body is sperated by `\r\n\r\n`).

<strike>I don't know which part of your setup is causing the error but you should check for that characters and if they exist, you know the file starts after `\r\n\r\n`.</strike>

You have something wrong in your request. The way you try to PUT the request is wrong.

[How to receive a file via HTTP PUT with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005790/how-to-receive-a-file-via-http-put-with-php)

**PUT**

> This directly complements GET. Where a GET requests indicates that the
>   server should return the document at the location specified by the
>   request URI in the response body, the PUT method indicates that the
>   server should store the data in the request body at the location
>   specified by the request URI.

This means, you may not have multipart request in a single PUT request.
There must be a single content-type. (Multipart is indicated by: `------WebKitFormBoundaryhPjNpS0gBhbCC8aR`)

In a POST request, there is multipart allowed (think of: `enctype='multipart/form-data'`).

A put request with a file must not contain anything else. Means, if you want to put a file + variables, the variables need to be appended to the URI, but not like in POST, in the body.

**Update with possible workaround** (I know it's a dirty solution, please don't blame me....):

```
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024)) {
    if (strpos($data, '\r\n\r\n') !== false) {
        $data = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data);  // seperate multipart header from body
        $data = $data[1];                    // assign body to $data
    } elseif(strpos($data, '\r\n-' !== false) {
        $data = explode("\r\n-", $data);  // seperate footer from body
        $data = $data[0];                    // assign body to $data
    }

    fwrite($fp, $data);
}
```

Comment: Useful information, but I am more interested in dropping this unwanted header and footer stuff entirely, as I can't be certain it will be identical on every request.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually the windows program nuget.exe that is going to ultimately be providing the request. Unfortunately, I have no ability to change how the requests are created so I have to figure out server-side how to strip it off.

Comment: @Jason I updated my answer... it's not a problem with the library but the way you make the put request.

Comment: Hmmm well like I mentioned, I have no actual control over the creation of the put request. With the nuget program, I get the following header: `-----------------------------8d16e4de44cb30d^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="package"; filename="package"^M
Content-Type: application/octet-stream^M
^M`. Since I can't change how it is sent, I'm gonna have to figure out how to strip this stuff out on the server side.

Comment: @JasonBray I'd rather fix the error in the program than implementing a workarround which might break later or lead to other issues. What is this nuget program?

Comment: nuget - https://www.nuget.org/ It's a commercial package manager presumably by microsoft. I'm attempting to write a custom feed in php.

Comment: Alternatively, if I could figure out a way to spoof the request as a POST, it would supposedly work, as that is what was done in an nginx environment because of precisely this issue. Unfortunately I cannot figure out if there is a way to do this in an apache environment. By spoof I mean, take the request, change the method and nothing else, and send it along.

Comment: Uff Microsoft,... haha :D Well maybe you are right and it's easier to strip the data. I''ll update my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Hey, Thanks Dan! I got it working finally, thanks for the code above, although there's a few errors in it. As I am fairly new to stackoverflow, am I supposed to edit your response or just add to mine above with the final solution?

Comment: @JasonBray It's always polite to ask. Feel free to edit my answer, we worked on it together :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there's something being added to the output. Open your ZIP file in a text editor and inspect the contents for warning messages/inadvertent output generated by your server/PHP.