# How can I send and receive put query with same script

Tags: php, put

I need to receive image send by PUT method. So I'm wrinting script for testing it. I want to receive and send it with the same script. How can I implement this? The following variant echoes nothing and string about Congratulations that http method was send ok.

```
<?php 
//if they DID upload a file...
var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])
{
    echo $_FILES['photo']['error'];
    if($_FILES['photo']['error']==0)
    {
        //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
        $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); //rename file
        $message = 'Congratulations!!!!!!!.';
            //move it to where we want it to be
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'url.../1.jpg');

            echo'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
            $image = fopen('url.../1.jpg', "rb");
            var_dump($image);
            $ch = curl_init();


            /* Set cURL options. */
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url.../upload.php");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $image);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($image));

            /* Execute the PUT and clean up */
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            fclose($image);             //recommended to close the fileshandler after action
            curl_close($ch);
    }
    //if there is an error...
    else
    {
        //set that to be the returned message
        $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['photo']['error'];
    }
}
else
{
    echo"WORKS";
}
```

Comment: You want to send back an image to the browser?

Comment: Yep, I need it for test. Next Another person from device will send me this image.

Answer (score 1):

The most easiest way to send back the image to a browser is via using a URL.

1. Process the image
2. Save the image somewhere on your sever
3. Send the URL back to browser.
4. Use a  tag at the browser and show your image.

> ```
> <?PHP 
>   $imgFile="";
>   if($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])
>   {
>       ///Your existing code
>       $imgFile="http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/Your image url here'; 
>       //Ex:\\ http://yourserver.com/images/1.jpg - 
>       //you can take this from your move_upload_file
>   }   
>
> ?>
> <img src="<?PHP echo $imgFile; ?>" />
> ```

Useful links [How to receive a file via HTTP PUT with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005790/how-to-receive-a-file-via-http-put-with-php)

Even for a restful service u can use json or xml to send the image url back. PUT is not a good idea unless u need to send back image data for some reason. May be u should rethink your logic?

Comment: Well, I do first 3 points as you can see at in my code. How can I do 4th point? I have no idea. Just tried to var_dump file_get_contents("php://input") and it shows zero.

Comment: Are u using ajax post or html post?

Comment: Well, html post. To send I use put method.

Comment: But I want to send it via  put method. As I understand this method just echoes image with certain url.

Comment: Probably got ur question wrong. U want to send to a different server via put?

Comment: Nope I want to send to my server via put to be able to test put methods on my server because next person will send me with put method some info from device.

Comment: I need it to create soft for receinving info.

Comment: Are u building some sort of api service?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63323/veeru - we can chat here, not recommended to have long conversation here.

Answer (score 0):

The mistakes was:
`strlen($image)` strlen if wrong, must be filesize and in my url I had `www`. It's not netion in my post but it was mistake.
More experienced programmer helped me.
r.php to read stream:

$res = file_get_contents("php://input");

```
$file = fopen('1.txt', "w");
fputs($file, $res);
fclose($file);

var_dump($res);
```

s.php to get stream and to init r.php

```
$image = fopen('/var/www/testfiles/1.jpg', "rb");
var_dump($image);
$ch = curl_init();


/* Set cURL options. */

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url withot www/r.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $image);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize('/var/www/testfiles/1.jpg'));

    /* Execute the PUT and clean up */
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    fclose($image);             //recommended to close the fileshandler after action
    curl_close($ch);

    die("OK");
```