# Alternative for PHP RESTful PUT method and multipart/form-data?

Tags: php, rest, multipartform-data, put

It's known by many that `PUT` request method and the `"multipart/form-data"` don't get along. Does anyone know of any alternatives for the `PUT` request method with large data?

I have been working on this shared virtual server with limited configuration flexibility, and changing `php_value post_max_size` is off the limit for me. So, I can never `POST` a large JSON via AJAX... unless I `POST` the JSON in binary like a file using `"multipart/form-data"` and `$_FILES`!

However this only works with the `POST` request method on Apache. With the RESTful `PUT` request method, I have no luck using `"multipart/form-data"` even if I use

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);
```

Just wondering if anyone has any alternative to `PUT` huge JSON to PHP/Apache.

Comment: Your solution is very hacky I too have never tried this but this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005790/how-to-receive-a-file-via-http-put-with-php

Comment: Hacky? is that not the ONLY way? With `php_value post_max_size` unchanged, I don't think there is any other way to send large JSON with `POST`.  if you know any other ways, please share. I really want to know. The link that you shared - to my understanding, it basically just says "No you can't do it. You just can't `PUT` a large JSON."